# Logic in Cshtml page to toggle between two different scripts based on web config value

Tags: razor

I have two scripts that I want to show on a page based on their web config values but I only want to allow one of them to be shown at all times.

```
@if (pageModel.ShowB || (pageModel.ShowA==1 && pageModel.ShowB==1) )
{
<!--script to implement B-->
}
@if (pageModel.ShowA)
{
<!--script to implement A-->
}
```

Would this be the best way of going about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your solution, but I would rather move the logic to the controller or where you build up the viewmodel. I prefer not to have logic in my razor files.

eg.

```
 public ActionResult Index(){
      if (pageModel.ShowB || (pageModel.ShowA==1 && pageModel.ShowB==1) )
      {
          ViewBag.PageScript = 'somescript.js'
      }else
      {
          ViewBag.PageScript = 'otherscript.js'
      }
```

Then in the view I would just do the script like this

```
  <script type="..." src="@ViewBag.PageScript"></script>
```